# views slideshow jquery interfering with nice menus

Tags: 6

Building a site for my friend who is a lawyer. Every time views slideshow changes slides, it resets the hover state for views slideshow. I tried calling the nice menu javascript at the bottom of the page but that did not help.

http://www.tripodi.devserver2012.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's `z-index` and it's a CSS issue, not a Javascript issue.

Put the following in your CSS sheet (any one of them that's included in your homepage):

```
#views_slideshow_singleframe_teaser_section_slideshow-block_1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.nice-menu li {
  z-index: 10;
}
```